# QGIS default style stored in PostGIS public.layer_styles table won't load with data from other schemas

Tags: qgis, postgis, layers, default

In QGIS 2.18.15 (and 3.0), I cannot get default styles stored in 'public.layer_styles' in a PostGIS database to load automatically when adding a new layer to the map.  I believe the problem is that the data layers are stored in different schema from 'public'.

The following approaches provide the desired result of automatically loading the default 'public.layer_styles' when a layer is added from the database:

1) 'public.layer_styles' column 'f_table_catalog' contains the name of the database, column 'f_table_schema' contains the name 'public' --> this only works if the data layers are ALSO stored in the 'public' schema.

[image: 'f_table_schema' column entry contains the text 'public']

2) 'public.layer_styles' column 'f_table_catalog' contains the name of the database, column 'f_table_schema' contains the name 'another_schema' (in this case 'dnk') --> this only works if the data layers are ALSO stored in the 'another_schema' schema (here, 'dnk').

[image: 'f_table_schema' column entry matches schema name where data layers are stored]

Option 2 above gets me most of the way to where I want to be.  The only problem is that it limits me to only being able to load data with default styles from one additional named schema ('dnk' in this case).  I have several other schemas in the same database from which I'd like to add data layers and have them styled automatically based on 'public.layer_styles'. I want to be able to load data layers from any named schema outside of 'public' and have the default layer_styles stored in 'public' be applied.

Is there some kind of wildcard character that can go in the 'f_table_schema' column to enable this (instead of 'public' or 'another_schema')?  Is there another way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: perhaps you should provide the complete layer_styles table (not only the two columns) in order to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are of course NOT limited to one specific schema (Why should this be exactly `dnk`?) besides `public` and QGIS loads default styles for whatever schema your tables are stored in (but first of all I strongly recommend to the latest QGIS Versions 2.18.22 LTR and/or 3.2 by Aug. 6th, 2018).

I have a layer `plz_by_31468` stored in a schema `plz` (without loss of generality), geometry column is `geom` (Postal code regions in Bavaria, Germany). If e.g. in QGIS 3.2 under Layer|Properties|Style|Style|Save Style|Save in database (postgres)

[image]

you save the style with e.g. the following settings:

[image]

you create the following entry in your `public.layer_styles` table:

[image]

and this style **definitely loads per default** (at least in the two latest versions mentioned above that I have access to).

If you have created the `public.layer_styles` table manually, make sure that the tables schema is in the `f_table_name`, that you have no misspellings in the `f_table_name` column and that the `useasdefault` column is set to some boolean `True` (`t`, `1`, ... should work also, cp. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-boolean.html for valid representations of boolean type in PostgreSQL) *only* for the style you want to load as default and `False` for any other.

Comment: Everything shown in your response I had already been doing...however, reading the response it finally occurred to me that it wasn't necessary to get a single style row in 'layer_styles' to apply to ALL other schemas in the database, which is what I was trying to do.  It became obvious that the solution to my problem is to load the layer_styles table with one row for each different 'f_table_schema' + 'f_table_name' combination I need styled.  I was trying to get a single row to apply to multiple 'f_table_schema' + 'f_table_name' combinations via a wildcard in 'f_table_schema'.  Thanks