# How to create a sub region shapefile from MasterMaps on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, os-mastermap

I have the OS `Mastermaps` on a `PostGIS` database and this is connected to `QGIS`. Mastermaps is visualised well on QGIS with all the layer styles.

A region is clipped from PostGIS and created a new table. When this is visualised on QGIS the layer styles are not visible as shown in the image.

[image]

I tried copying the layer style from the original layer to the new layer but still it does not show on the layer. However in the properties the new style can be seen.

Can you please help me to apply the original styles to this new layer and save as a shapefile?

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291727/qgis-default-style-stored-in-postgis-public-layer-styles-table-wont-load-with-d

Comment: This looks like the Mastermap topographic area layer (Mastermap has a number of layers). What you're seeing in the blue version is simply a default style - which suggests that you've not been successful in copying and pasting the style. If you check the styling for the original layer, it's probably based on the style_code field. For troubleshooting I'd start by creating a new style based on that field - it doesn't have to be pretty. Also check that the style_code field has made it through the transition to Shapefile. Is it present? Is the field name identical?